# show text with diagonal line in d3 tree graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 js to display data in graph view . Everything is working fine but I need one enhancement . I wanted to show some text above the diagonal line so that user can know how two nodes are related to each other .

Diagonal is created using below mentioned function but how to append text I don't know

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection(function(d) {
            console.log(d)
            return [d.y, d.x];
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem . Add below code to update function

```
// Update the link text
var linktext = svg.selectAll("g.link")
    .data(links, function (d) {
    return d.target.id;
});                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

linktext.enter()
    .insert("g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function (d) {
    //console.log(d.target.name);
    return d.target.name;
});
```

For more info look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617501/unable-to-add-text-on-link-in-d3-collapsible-tree) and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/82pepd2a/9/)